# Combining text with data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a string like follows.

```
string someInfo = string.Format("First Name = {0}, Last Name = {1}",firstName, lastName);
```

This string need to be displayed in application using TextBlock. The first and last names are coming from database so I would like to using data bindings for this. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible.

However, because you have multiple bindings, you need to bind to a `MultiBinding` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Your binding looks like:

```
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}">
      <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
      <Binding Path="LastName"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
```

With a `MultiValueConverter`:

```
public class NameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format("First Name = {0}, Last Name = {1}", values[0], values[1]);
    }
    public objct ConvertBack(...)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this in a Page object, and doesn't seem like I can declare Windows.Resources in the Page XAML. Any ideas?

Comment: @johnsmith How about `<Page.Resources>` :)

Comment: With <Page.Resources>  <Converter:NameConverter x:Key="NameConverter" /> </Page.Resources> I get "The namespace prefix "Converter" is not defined". How can I findout which namespace should be associated with Converter?

Comment: @johnsmith You have to define the namespace your converter is in as an `xmlns` (they are at the top in the `Page` tag). Plenty of good examples out there...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you use the MVVM pattern. if you do just define a property in your ViewModel

```
public string Someinfo
{
 get { return string.Format("First Name = {0}, Last Name = {1}",firstName, lastName);}
}
```

and then use a Binding in your Xaml

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Path Someinfo} />
```

I would say this is 'cleaner' than doing that in your xaml.

Comment: While this is a reasonable way to accomplish this, you need to account for the additional complexity in raising INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1):

yes it possible

```
public  string SomeInfo { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SomeInfo = GetFirstNameAndLastNameFromDataBase();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private string GetFirstNameAndLastNameFromDataBase()
        {
            string firstName = "firstName";
            string lastName = "lastName";

            return string.Format("First Name = {0}, Last Name = {1}", firstName, lastName);
        }



<Window x:Class="BindingToTextBlock.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeInfo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```